# Why is "Mae" increasing when tuning a model RFR model

Tags: python, random-forest, evaluation, grid-search

I have a problem where the Mean absolute error increases when tuning the parameters for RandomForestRegressor. I have set the scoring to `neg_mean_absolute_error` but for some reason it still increases?

My dataset contains 100.000 observations across 300 variables where i have used a *train/test* split with a `test_size=0.2`.

I have tried 200 combinations with randomgridsearchcv where i set `scoring=neg_mean_absolute_error`. When measuring the MAE on the test data i get a `mae=6500` (default RFR model) and on the tuned model i get an `mae=9000`. shouldn't it decrease or at least stay the same? it seems like it is underfitting the model when tuning it

The code I've used to tune the model looks like this:

```
max_features=['auto','sqrt']
min_samples_split = [2,5,10,20,30,40]
min_samples_leaf = [5,10,20,50,60,80]
max_depth = [int(x) for x in np.linspace(5, 200, num = 20)]

random_grid = {'max_features': max_features,
               'max_depth': max_depth,
               'min_samples_split': min_samples_split,
               'min_samples_leaf': min_samples_leaf
               }

kf = KFold(n_splits=3, random_state=1)

rfr=RandomForestRegressor(n_estimators=100)
rfr_random=RandomizedSearchCV(estimator = rfr,
                              param_distributions=random_grid,
                              n_iter=200,
                              cv=kf,
                              n_jobs=-1,
                              random_state=53,
                              scoring='neg_mean_absolute_error')

rfr_random.fit(x_train,y_train)

RF=RandomForestRegressor(**rfr_random.best_params_)
RF.fit(x_train,y_train)

y_pred=RF.predict(x_test)
print('Mean Absolute Error:', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_test, y_pred))
```

Can anyone explain why the MAE increases when optimizing the initial model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen.

You are training on the trainset, this does not mean that it fits good for the test set.
Did you predict it for the training set?

```
y_pred_train=RF.predict(x_train)
print('Mean Absolute Error (Train):', metrics.mean_absolute_error(y_train, y_pred_train))
```

If this error is quite small, you have done a overfit! That means that you have a 'perfect' prediction for your train data, but does not work for your test data.

in your case you could try a : k-fold cross valdiation. This basically will try several train/test-splits to find the best prediction.

Also good for you devide your dataset it in train, dev and test set. (test and dev size = 0.2 in total e.g.). then you do training, try it on dev set, tune training again, try it on dev set and after you have a good result, roll it out on test set, and then you see if it was really good!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I have tried to predict on the train where i get a small error, suggesting overfitting in the train dataset. I am using a Kfold cross validation approach when tuning the parameters to minimize overfitting. Since the tuned model results in a higher error should i not just choose the default model since its performance on unseen data (x_test) seems to be better? I have tried different random states for both the train/test split and the results seems consistent on the test data.

Comment: so I would try to split it in Train, dev and test now. And then train the algorithm to have a nice result for the dev set, then it should work

Comment: When you advise on splitting it into development set would you manually tune the model and predict on the dev set? or is it possible to incorporate that in gridsearchcv?

Comment: As gridsearch does not lead to a sucess, you should also try a manual approach, sometimes the manual approach leads to better insights and a good learning